# Wiring new 'c' wire to heat pump system. Do I need to connect at both air handler and condenser?

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I am planning on installing a new WIFI thermostat (Honeywell RTH6580WF).  I have a heat pump system (outdoor condenser unit and air handler in attic).  Old thermostat did not have a 'c' wire, but it does have an extra wire in the bundle that I can use.

Do I need to connect the new 'c' wire on both units?  Or will hooking the one to the air handler be enough?

Answer (score 1):

You should connect the `C` wire, from whichever unit supplies the `R` wire. Typically it's the air handler, but since you've given no details it's impossible to say for sure.